# Working on a express app with React frontend, git add -A doesn't add client changes

Tags: git

Hi I'm building my first express app with a React client running concurrently. When I git add -A in the server folder it adds everything but the changes made in the client(React) folder stay red and un-added. I pushed anyway, cd'ed into the client folder, git add -A and made a git commit -m  message, but when I went to git push it says there is No configured push destination. When I cd back into the server folder and git push, it says everything up to date. When I git status I still see un-pushed changes in the client folder in red. Any help?

```js
-.git
-client
--src
--package.json
--node_modules
-package.json
-node_modules
```

Comment: please add your repo dir hierarchy and mention where **.git** file is

Comment: @NaorTedgi Thanks Naor! Just updated the post with a rough idea of the directory.